# Sort list of objects by list of objects inside it

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have home object : id , FirstName, Lastname, Fees[ ]

Fees is object contain Amount description

home object include the Fees array

I have list of homes and every home has array/list from fees

I need to sort the homes depend on the total of Amount in fees

```
List <home> h = new List <home>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have an object structure like this:

```
class Home
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Fee[] Fees { get; set; }
}

class Fee
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

You can sort it using the following statement:

```
var orderedHomes = homes.OrderBy(x => x.Fees.Sum(y => y.Amount));
```

Comment: Thank you , It works, your answer is perfect.
Appreciate your help
Thank you.

Comment: I Marked as "The Answer", Thank you and appreciate your advices and your support.